# XML Sitemap YoastSEO

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При открытии карты Sitemap почему то 3 sitemap

как сделать одно целое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или такой вариант самый правильный

Comment: Этот вариант самый правильный. Его не просто так придумали. Все-таки у плагина более 1 млн активных установок. Так что примите это как есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так сейчас **`yoast`** вырисовывает sitemap. Это нормально, поисковик всё поймёт.

В настройках плагина, на странице xml-карта cайта во вкладке **`Типы записей`** вы можете управлять категориями которые будут попадать в sitemap.